# while running hadoop fs -ls getting error no cldb entries

Tags: mapreduce, mapr

while running hadoop fs -ls getting error, please see below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When running "hadoop fs -ls", the list of CLDB servers will be read from the /opt/mapr/conf/mapr-clusters.conf file.  That file should be populated based on the CLDB addresses provided when running the /opt/mapr/server/configure.sh command.  Either, the contents of mapr-clusters.conf do not specify the correct CLDB hosts (or any servers), or the CLDB service is not running on the specified hosts.  I'd suggest ensuring the MapR services are running on the nodes where they've been installed and reviewing the installation/configuration documentation.